# jQuery/JS Text input select

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, input

I'm searching for a jQuery or simple, old-school JavaScript script which makes text input fields behave like on this picture:

[image]

There was a few days ago a link on twitter to such a plugin but I wasn't able to find it again (with Google, Browser History, Twitter-Search etc.).

Comment: Can you link to a live example?  I can't tell if that is auto-complete or tags that gets inserted as you type.

Comment: Perhaps you can better describe what the textbox is doing? Does it make some sort of list from what you type and you can delete each item? Just not quite sure what the [Test Bla x] thing is doing.

Comment: Here is an example how it should behave/look like: http://devthought.com/wp-content/articles/autocompletelist/test.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, this'll help you to get started.

[Facebook style input box](http://ajaxian.com/archives/facebook-style-input-box)

Comment: Yes, this is like I want to have it, but isn't here a jQuery plugin of it? (This link includes a MooTools/Prototype version)

Comment: jquery plugin? I am sure there is one, just search for facebook style tagging or something similar you will find them

Comment: yep thats a good one, just play around with the CSS to make it have the design you want, you can put it in a box to have the input effect and other things. Glad you found it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [jQuery UI's Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)? The styling can be easily achieved using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This one is my favorite (its a jQuery plugin): http://documentcloud.github.com/visualsearch/